# Adding column value labels to R googleVis gvisColumnChart?

Tags: r, google-visualization, googlevis

Does anybody know how to add column value labels to a gvisColumnChart()?

There are so many options to go through, and I'm sure I'm not the first with this question. It would be really helpful for my project...

Edit: By value labels I mean something like this (numbers written on the bars themselves):

[image: Chart with bar value labels]

I'm using R 3.2.0 and googleVis 0.5.8

The answer for JS is here:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart

Essentially creating a secondary `view` element and adding it to the plot:

```
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1,
                   { calc: "stringify",
                     sourceColumn: 1,
                     type: "string",
                     role: "annotation" },
                   2]);

  var options = {...};
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
  chart.draw(view, options);
```

I just don't quite know how to pass this extra element via R. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution in R.

Googlevis expects at an x-axis label column and at least one named data column. I duplicated the data column, resulting in a a three column dataset, in my case it's called chartset.

Name the third column after the data column ("Percentage" in my case) and add "**.annotation**" to the name, thus "Percentage.annotation". The googlevis interpreter is smart enough to pick up on it and throw the third column in as an annotation.

```
  setnames(chartset, c("Answer","Percentage","Percentage.annotation"))
  p1 <- gvisColumnChart(chartset, xvar="Answer",  yvar=c('Percentage',                       
                        'Percentage.annotation'), options=list(title= ccTitle,
                         vAxes="[{minValue:0}]"))
  p1
```

[image]